# Python function argument not taking expected if else statement result

Tags: python

I am using the function argument in Python, and expecting the output based on the argument.
Code is as below:

```
DATA1 = ''
DATA2 = ''
item_select = 'D970'

def Display_DATA1(FALT_ARRAY):
   if(FALT_ARRAY == DATA1):
      request = '22 D9 70'
      print '1st' +' '+ request
   elif(FALT_ARRAY == DATA2):
      request = '22 D9 71'
      print '2nd' +' '+ request

if (item_select == 'D970'):
    Display_DATA1(DATA1);
elif(item_select == 'D971'):
    Display_DATA1(DATA2);
```

Expecting output as:

```
if:item_select = 'D970'
```

print `'1st 22 D9 70`

```
if:item_select = 'D971'
```

print `'1st 22 D9 71`

Now I am getting value for `item_select = 'D971'` as `'1st 22 D9 70` which is not correct.

Let me know, what exactly do i need to change in code. Is any alternative way to write code for argument.

Comment: Your `DATA1` and `DATA2` are identical. And why differentiate between them **before** calling `Display_DATA1` and then differentiating between them **again**?

Comment: DATA1 and DATA2 are empty??

Comment: The code does not make a lot of sense. Are you sure you have the right code here?

Comment: @SRC...The code correct, expecting the whats is wrong in my code, which is not getting result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your DATA1 and DATA2 are identical. Set like this it will work
`DATA1 = '1'`

`DATA2 = '2'`